# Which static site generator has the most full GitLab Flavored Markdown support?

Tags: gitlab, markdown, static-site-generation

I want to create a static site, which will store documentation, written in GitLab Flavored Markdown. Which static site generator has the most full GitLab Flavored Markdown support?

Comment: This page could help you. https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/06/17/ssg-overview-gitlab-pages-part-3-examples-ci/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that there is any static site generator (SSG) that supports GitLab Flavored markdown specifically.

However, [as documented](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html), GitLab markdown uses [CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/) as a basis.

CommonMark has a [list of SSGs](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-spec/wiki/Applications-supporting-CommonMark#static-site-generators) that support it out of the box.

So that's probably the closest you'll get.